# Git - Checkout duration fluctuation?

Tags: git, version-control

I develop locally on a Vagrant box, and push my changes from my local repo to my private GitLab server. From there, I merge into master, and pull these changes on the production server. The command I use for pulling on production:

```
git fetch --all
git checkout --force {last-commit-ref}
```

Now, sometimes this literally takes a split-second. It only touches the files that changed, and it's no problem. But sometimes it takes like 30 seconds. You get some kind of counter like 2574/3601 objects or something, and files are out of sync.

It doesn't seem to be a case of the more files the longer it takes.

Why does a checkout like this sometimes takes a split-second and sometimes a century? It seems like when it takes 30 seconds, it checks out every file again- even if they didn't change?

Edit: To clarify, it's `git checkout` that takes a long time, not `git fetch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--

### ***`Update`***

After a long chat with the asker, i found out that he had a hook which updates all the files (chmod). So every time git updates he had to do it all over again.

Switching to the desired user fixed the problem.

---

When you run a fetch its downloading **all** the changes from the remote.
That's what fetch do. When you checkout it checkout locally the desired commit once it was downloaded.

The `git fetch` download all the content form the remote repository so your local will be fully synched with the remote and you have the same copy as the remote (without your changes on the remote).

Sometimes git need some time to download and re-pack the content.

Comment: Problem is that the fetch only takes half a second. It's the checkout that takes a long time, even if only 1 file changes. It seems to re-write every single file in the repo to the disk, even if they haven't changed. Fetch is not the problem.

Comment: So you must have a huge repo. what is the size of your `.git` folder? It its more then few MB it will effect performance, Its too long to write here how does git pack and extract content but basically its splitted to many small hunks and git need to build those content from the hunks on every checkout. so if your pack file is BIg it might take a while

Comment: The .git folder is 20MB. The thing I don't get is why sometimes it's instant and sometimes it takes 30 seconds, for the same amount of files?

Comment: So it must be something with your OS or the VM. try to optimize the size with this command (Might be dangerous if you dont know what it does)  `git gc --aggressive --prune=now`. It will delete all the leftover by git and will repack and optimize your pack files

Comment: Tried that command, and it's still doing the same thing. Screenshot of what I get: http://i.imgur.com/aZXiXKr.png. In this commit, I changed 2 files. Why is it checking out 6393 files?

Comment: Its not checking out files, its the fetch, git download your content form the remote, you have a lot of new code committed. Git downloads it all and then re-pack your content. Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Eh? But git fetch finishes in half a second. Git fetch downloads the content from the remote, right? This finishes in half a second. Then, only when I do git commit gfdgdf....... it takes a long, long time. In this specific commit, there were 15 additions and 5 deletions in 2 files. Then why does it checkout 6393 files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110237/discussion-between-codewizard-and-basaa).

Comment: After an extremely helpful CodeWizard in the chat we managed to figure out the problem: I was checking out with a different user than the owner of the files, forcing GIT to touch every file. Huge thanks to CodeWizard!